# Differentiability of $\lvert\cos x\rvert$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

I don't know if I understand differentiability and continuity. So by my understanding, if a function is continuous at a point, it may or may not be differentiable at that point; but if it isn't continuous at some point, then it can't be differentiable at that point. So  for functions I can first test the continuity, then the differentiability. If a function is continuous at that point I can use the differentiation rules, if I am not allowed to test continuity first, then I have to do it by definition of a derivative.

For $f(x)=\lvert\cos x\rvert$, that function is continuous on all $\mathbb R$, but we have to check at a point $x= \pi/2$, since the absolute value is $0$ there, and check it by definition. I don't quite understand is the function differentiable or not. When  find the right and left derivative, they turn out the same to me, but in my answer sheet it says it isn't for $\pi/2$.

Comment: What did you find for the left and right derivative?

Comment: @ConMan I found zeros.

Comment: Then I suggest you check again, and maybe also draw the graph.

Comment: For the left derivative, say $x\in [0, \pi/2]$, then $f(x) = \lvert\cos x \rvert = \cos x$. What is the derivative of $\cos x$ at $x=\pi/2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, there is a theorem which says that if a function $f$ is differentiable at some point in its domain, then it is continuous at that point.  However, this is not a very useful result for checking differentiability—it is useful for showing that a function is *not* differentiable (i.e. if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, then $f$ is certainly not differentiable at $a$).  This theorem is a bit of a red herring with respect to the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by the formula $$f(x) = \lvert \cos(x)\rvert,$$ since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

   Indeed, it isn't too hard to see that $f$ is continuous:  there is a another theorem which states that the composition of continuous functions is continuous, and $f$ is the composition of the functions $g$ and $h$, given by the formulae
   $$ g(x) = \lvert x \rvert
   \qquad\text{and}\qquad
   h(x) = \cos(x) $$
   (that is, $f = g\circ h$).  Both $g$ and $h$ are continuous, so $f$ is continuous as well.

   But, again, continuity is a bit of a red herring here.
2. The cosine function is periodic with period $2\pi$, from which it follows that the function $f$, defined by $f(x) = \lvert \cos(x)\rvert$, is $2\pi$-periodic.  Thus, in order to determine the differentiability of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, it is sufficient to show that it is differentiable on the closed interval $[0,2\pi]$.

   - if $x \in [0,\pi/2) \cup (3\pi/2,2\pi]$, then $\cos(x) > 0$, from which it follows that
     \begin{align*}
     f(x) = \lvert \cos(x) \rvert = \cos(x) \implies f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \cos(x) = \sin(x).
     \end{align*}
   - if $x \in (\pi/2,3\pi/2)$, then $\cos(x) < 0$, from which it follows that
     \begin{align*}
     f(x) = \lvert \cos(x) \rvert = -\cos(x) \implies f'(x) = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \cos(x) = -\sin(x).
     \end{align*}
   - if $x = \pi/2$ or $x = 3\pi/2$, then $\cos(x) = 0$, and there is a bit of a problem using known derivatives to compute $f'$, since $\cos$ is being composed with the absolute value, which is not differentiable when $x=0$.  It is not automatically true that $f$ is not differentiable, which means that something needs to be done to determine whether or not $f$ is differentiable here.

     In general, I prefer to use more elementary tools for a problem like this, so recall the definition of the derivative: if the derivative of $f$ exists, then it is given by a limit (and if that limit doesn't exist, then the derivative does not exit).  Evaluating the limit (and abusing notation a bit) gives
     \begin{align}
     \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(\pi/2 + h) - f(\pi/2)}{h}
     &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\lvert \cos(\pi/2+h) \rvert - \lvert \cos(\pi/2) \rvert}{h} \\
     &= \begin{cases}
     \displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\cos(\pi/2+h)  - 0}{h} & \text{if $0<h$, and} \\[2ex]
     \displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-\cos(\pi/2+h)  - 0}{h} & \text{if $0>h$,}
     \end{cases} \\
     &= \begin{cases}
     1 & \text{if $0<h$, and} \\
     -1 & \text{if $0>h$.}
     \end{cases}
     \end{align}
     The left-hand and right-hand limits disagree, so the limit does not exist.  Therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $\pi/2$.  By similar reasoning, it fails to be differentiable at $3\pi/2$, or at either of these points plus an even multiple of $\pi$.
3. It is often helpful to look at the graph of a function when trying to work out differentiability of a function.  This is not a *rigorous* approach, but the graph can give insight into where one should focus their attention.  In the case of $\lvert \cos(x)\rvert$, the graph is given by

   [image]

   A differentiable function must be "smooth"—it does not have "cusps" or "corners".  The graph of this function has cusps at odd multiples of $\pi/2$, which suggests that this function is not differentiable at these points.  This further suggests that when trying to determine whether or not this function is differentiable, one should focus their attention on these cusp points.

Comment: Is there a function which geometrically doesn't have cusps or corners but is NOT smooth?

Comment: @monoidaltransform Well, presumably, you are excluding functions with jump discontinuities, which also fail to be differentiable.  In this case, *yes*, such functions exist, but they are a little harder to construct.  I would suggest that something like $x\sin(1/x)$ might fit the category of function you are looking for---the function is continuous at zero, but it oscillates very quickly around zero, and the derivative is poorly behaved.  There are also functions which have corners or cusps which are very hard to see in a computer generated graph...

Comment: ...for example, consider a function which is given by $3x$ for $x < 0$, and $3.0000001 x$ for $x \ge 0$.  This function is not differentiable at zero, but if you graph it, it is going to be hard to see this cusp or corner.

Comment: Thanks Really informative. Liked and upvoted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}+} \frac{|cos(x)|-|cos(\frac{\pi}{2})|}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}+}\frac{-cos(x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}+}\frac{sin(x)}{1}=1
\end{equation}
The cosine function is negative when $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ from the right side. I also used the L'Hospital rule. On the other hand:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}-} \frac{|cos(x)|-|cos(\frac{\pi}{2})|}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}-}\frac{cos(x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}-}\frac{-sin(x)}{1}=-1
\end{equation}
The cosine function is positive when $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ from the left side. I also used the L'Hospital rule.
Since the limits do not have the same (finite) value, the function is not differentiable at $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You can try the similar exercise with $g(x)=|sin(x)|$ at $x_0=0$. Similar conclusions can be derived for all of the other zeros of these functions.